# Native Encode Support

Tags: php, character-encoding, ascii, encode

A simple and stupid question that im wondering.

I saw in the [PHP Manul](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) that PHP only supports a 256-character set.
But is not specified if is the ASCII code.

From the PHP manual i found [This page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.international.php)
That confuse me more.

I wanna know if depends of the operating system.

Native support from PHP are the ASCII code?
One document that stipulate it?

What about [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.international.php) Encode supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses ASCI characters each of a byte containing 8 bit. That's all.

PHP doesn't care about the interpretation of each byte, it just reads from a source or writes to a sink.

To which specific [code-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) these bytes belong doesn't matter. PHP doesn't care about it.

If your PHP-Script interacts with a web-server, each page should contain a hint, which defines the correct interpreation in the `<head>` of a `<html>` page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
```

The above declaration defines, that the characters of the HTML-page should be interpreted as **ISO Latin-1** codes. Additionally, if the page sends back characters to the PHP-script, the browser sends them as **ISO Latin-1** encoded ASCII characters.

If you forget to define a **Content-Type**, it's up to the browser to use a code page / text encoding.

That said, you are free to use any ASCII text-encoding that best fits your needs. But never forget to set a **Content-Type** in a web-page.

Extensions like [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) help out, in case you need to process e.g. UTF-8 characters.